# Citation Breaking Across Lines

Tags: line-breaking, citing

I have a citation that is being split across 2 lines.  Specifically, I have "author last name" at the end of the first line and "(Year)" at the start of the second line.  I want both pieces to be on the same line, as I feel it looks strange the way it is now.

How do I prevent this from occurring?  I read a thread where someone suggested using mbox, but this pushed the text into the margin when I tried it.

Comment: Also, I'm not using any modified citation commands.  Just a standard \cite{}

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  if you don't want this string broken, then you have to accept the consequences of putting it all on one line.  `\mbox` will keep it as a unit; to move the unit to the next line, wrap the paragraph in `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}`.  if you don't like the result, then we will need to see a compilable example that demontrates the problem, in order to have a better idea of the specifics.

Comment: Thanks! It worked and it looks reasonably good, so I'm satisfied with it.  Much appreciated